# Choose image URL from large array, insert into random DIV on page, cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bit of an odd request. I have ~300 image URLs and 27 `div`s. Each `div` has an `id="img1"`, where `1` is a number between 1 and (you guessed it) 27, and a `class="imageblock"` (for general styling).

Into each of these `div`s, I'd like to insert an `<img src="http://foo.bar/img.jpg" width="640">`, where the URL is chosen from a list of about 300 randomly, and inserted into one of the `div`s randomly. Each of the 27 `div`s should have its own image chosen from the 300 options.

Furthermore, these images should cycle. Every 5 seconds, I'd like to have one random image URL on the page replaced with another random one.

This is the (terrible) code I have attempted to cobble together with a little help, but I'm useless with javascript and can't make this work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $('document').ready(function() {        
                    var divs = $('div');

                        $("div").each(function() {
                          $(this).html("<img src='http://foo.bar/img1.jpg'alt='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'/>");         
                        });  

                        var imageChanger = setInterval(function() {switchImage()}, 500);


                        function switchImage() {
                         var new_image_url = [ 'http://foo.bar/anotherimg.jpg', 'http://bar.foo/image.jpg', 'http://foo.bar/imgremote.jpg'];

                            var random_div = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('div').length);
                            var random_img = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(new_image_url.length);

                          $("div:nth-child("+random_div+")").html('<img src="('+random_img+')" width="640">)');            

                        }
    });
    </script>
```

Note that the remote images do not follow any common pattern, thereby rendering my `random_img` variable unworking.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select a random element from an array, you can use this:

```
var random_div = divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)];
var random_img = new_image_url[Math.floor(Math.random() * new_image_url.length)];
```

Here's a slightly more efficient version of your code:

```
function random_int(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ['http://foo.bar/anotherimg.jpg', 'http://bar.foo/image.jpg', 'http://foo.bar/imgremote.jpg'];
    var $divs = $('div');

    $divs.each(function() {
        $('<img />', {
            src: 'http://foo.bar/img1.jpg',
            alt: this.id
        }).appendTo(this);
    });

    function switchImage() {
        var $div = $divs.eq(random_int($divs.length));
        var image = images[random_int(images.length)];

        $div.find('img').attr('src', image);
    }

    var imageChanger = setInterval(switchImage, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working well. The only thing I'm confused about now is this:

    $("div:nth-child("+random_div+")").html("<img src='("+random_img+")' width="640">");

It's writing the parentheses.

Comment: Hey, I can just remove the parentheses. That was pretty dumb of me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Much cleaner than mine. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.