# Populate multiple divs with images from array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a page which contains 15 div elements. I need to populate each div with a random image from an array of at least 36 images. I then need to have the images rotate at random intervals. I have this part working with a solution provided in [Choose image URL from large array, insert into random DIV on page, cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649972/choose-image-url-from-large-array-insert-into-random-div-on-page-cycle).

I would like to improve on the code so that images are not allowed to be called from the array if they are already being displayed on the page. This is what I'm stuck on.

This is my code so far.

```
function random_int(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var images = ['http://placekitten.com/159/159', 'http://placekitten.com/160/160', 'http://placekitten.com/161/161', 'http://placekitten.com/162/162', 'http://placekitten.com/163/163', 'http://placekitten.com/164/164', 'http://placekitten.com/165/165', 'http://placekitten.com/166/166', 'http://placekitten.com/167/167', 'http://placekitten.com/168/168', 'http://placekitten.com/169/169', 'http://placekitten.com/170/170', 'http://placekitten.com/171/171', 'http://placekitten.com/172/172', 'http://placekitten.com/173/173', 'http://placekitten.com/174/174', 'http://placekitten.com/175/175', 'http://placekitten.com/176/176', 'http://placekitten.com/177/177', 'http://placekitten.com/178/178', 'http://placekitten.com/179/179'];
            var $divs = $('div.projectItem');

            $divs.each(function() {
                $('<img width="100%" />', {
                    src: 'http://placekitten.com/180/180',
                    alt: this.id
                }).appendTo(this);
            });

            function switchImage() {
                var $div = $divs.eq(random_int($divs.length));
                var image = images[random_int(images.length)];

                $div.find('img').attr('src', image);
            }

            var imageChanger = setInterval(switchImage, 500);
        });
```

[I have created a JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dc1000/3Et38/).

One other thing I would like to achieve is to have an image in each div when the page first loads. You will notice in the jsfiddle example that the divs are empty and can stay that way for some time after the page has loaded. I have tried including an initial img tag in each div but when the random images are loaded, they do not replace the initial images and each div ends up with two images in it. I believe this is because of the `.appendTo(this);`. I think I have to change this to `replaceChild` or similar?

Any assistance appreciated by a first-time poster and JS beginner.

Comment: When you say that you want the images to initially load on the page do you want those images to be random as well?

Comment: @hitautodestruct that would be ideal, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the image from array each time you adding it.
Once you replace the image, don't forget to push the image from the IMG tag into the array.

Something like this:

```
function random_int(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ['http://placekitten.com/159/159', 'http://placekitten.com/160/160', 'http://placekitten.com/161/161', 'http://placekitten.com/162/162', 'http://placekitten.com/163/163', 'http://placekitten.com/164/164', 'http://placekitten.com/165/165', 'http://placekitten.com/166/166', 'http://placekitten.com/167/167', 'http://placekitten.com/168/168', 'http://placekitten.com/169/169', 'http://placekitten.com/170/170', 'http://placekitten.com/171/171', 'http://placekitten.com/172/172', 'http://placekitten.com/173/173', 'http://placekitten.com/174/174', 'http://placekitten.com/175/175', 'http://placekitten.com/176/176', 'http://placekitten.com/177/177', 'http://placekitten.com/178/178', 'http://placekitten.com/179/179'];
    var $divs = $('div.projectItem');

    $divs.each(function() {
        $('<img width="100%" />', {
            src: 'http://placekitten.com/180/180',
            alt: this.id
        }).appendTo(this);
    });

    function switchImage() {
        var $div = $divs.eq(random_int($divs.length));
        var image_i = random_int(images.length);
        var image = images[image_i];
        var $img = $div.find('img');

        images.splice(images_i,1);
        images.push($img.attr("src"));

        $img.attr('src', image);
    }

    var imageChanger = setInterval(switchImage, 500);
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't quite solve it. I had to change `images.splice(images_i,1);` to `images.splice(image_i,1);` for anything to happen, and then duplicates were still showing.